# How to pass selected check-box value(s) from jQuery to PHP as an array?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

UPDATED CODE:

Now, I have this code:

```
<h2>Testing</h2>

<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit1" id="id1"  class="box">Banana<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit2" id="id2"  class="box">Cherry<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit3" id="id3"  class="box">Strawberry<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit4" id="id4"  class="box">Orange<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="fruit5" id="id5"  class="box">Peach<br /><br />
<form id="myForm" action="2.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="groupdelete" value="clickme"><br />
</form>     

<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$('#groupdelete').on('click', function(){
var names = [];
$('input:checked').each(function() {
    names.push($(this).attr("id"));

});

$.post("2.php", { "names" : names }, function(data) {
    names = names.join(",");
    // do something on success
    alert(data); //if everything is working correctly should alert the var_dump here
});
});

</script>
```

On page 2.php I have this:

```
<?php
$names = explode(",",$_POST['names']);
var_dump($names);
?>
```

Which prints: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

What I am doing wrong???

Zoran

Comment: You could change it into an array using php via the http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php explode function.

Comment: `id` attribute value that starts with a number is **invalid!**

Comment: I get no erros. I get string(3)"2,3" if I select checkboxes 2 and 3. I need the value to be passed as an array. Yes frank, I know to do that, but is something that I am trying to avoid, since it should be possible to pass the value as an array.

Comment: -gdoron, yes I know, but changing the id to start with the letter, will not do the trick.

Comment: no error Gaurav...I get coma separated string, and I need an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send an ajax request to the server

```
names.push($(this).attr("id"));

$('#groupdelete').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the default form action
    var names = [];
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        names.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });

    $.post("page2.php", { "names" : names }, function(data) {
        // do something on success
        alert(data); //if everything is working correctly should alert whatever page2.php echos or prints
    });

});
```

---

#### Update 1

JS Array and PHP array are two different things and an easy way to overcome this is join

```
names = names.join(","); //Join all the array with a comma nd send
```

Later on the PHP Script, use explode() to get your array back

```
$names = explode(",",$_POST['names']);
var_dump($names);
```

#### Update 2

Make the following changes on your current code

```
names = names.join(",");
$.post("2.php", { "names" : names }, function(data) {
    alert(data); //if everything is working correctly should alert the var_dump here
});
```

#### Update 3

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/LdCFK/1/), with the proper way to do it. Check it and update your codes as per.

#### Update 4

Ok, finally starting the get the picture now. Check [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/LdCFK/2/).

Basically, create a hidden element, whose value will be updated with the checked box's id value and send it.

#### Update 5

If you want to stop a field from being submitted. You can assign `disabled="disabled"` to stop it from being submitted.

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/LdCFK/3/)

Comment: Hi Starx my page 2.php prints null. any idea why?

Comment: @user1004754, I am not sure if you used my code properly, check my update and as per that.

Comment: @user1004754, Please use proper name instead of the codename generated by this site.

Comment: Hi Starx. Your code works only if i remove <form action=2.php method post> and </form> tags. How can I redirect the user without the form action? Sorry about my name, but I can't find where to change it.

Comment: @user1004754, `groupdelete` is a submit button, on it will trigger the submit event of the form. use `event.preventDefault()` on the code to stop the submition

Comment: @user1004754, Change your name by opening your profile by clicking in your userid at the top of the page.

Comment: Starx, I updated the code per your instructions, but I still get an empty array? Please take a look on my edited code and let me know what I am doing wrong? Regards, Zoran

Comment: still get just:array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Thanks...my only problem now is to send this data to 2.php Because of prevent.default, information never reach the 2.php. Stop on alert

Comment: Believe or not, i have this again:array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } Also one more detail. I do want to use hidden, but i want checkboxes to be out of the <form></form> tags, is that possible. The need the checkboxes to be out of the <form></form> tags was the reason why I turn to jquery solution.

Comment: Btw, thanks a ton for your help man, I am bumping my head against the wall 2 days with this.

Comment: I want this to be submitted: 'code'<form id="myForm" action="2.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="actualvalue" name="actualvalue" />
    <input type="submit" id="groupdelete" value="clickme">
</form> 'code'

Comment: @Zoran, My update works. Remove the `e.preventDefault()` to get the form submitted.

Comment: Indeed works. Problem was that I didn't notice that you change the hidden name in actualvalue from names as it was. As soon as I change that, everything works like a charm. Thanks a ton man

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

## HTML form

```html
<form id="myForm" action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="1">Banana<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="2">Cherry<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="3">Strawberry<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="4">Orange<br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="5">Peach<br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="groupdelete" value="clickme"><br />
</form>
```

## jQuery code

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Will post: " + $(this).serialize());
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    });
});
```

## PHP code

```php
var_dump($_POST);
```

## Output

Assuming the first two check-boxes were checked:

```
array(1) {
  ["fruit"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It always gives me an array with _values_ of checked elements. Note that I've dropped the id attribute and added value attribute to each check-box (look at the html form closely).